# Finding subitems in an AdapterView

Tags: android, android-listview

(In Android) I have a list with an AdapterView, of course, and the view has two items - a string item and an image.  The user clicks on the string item (the image is not visible) and my ItemClickListener gets invoked.  I can find out what position was clicked.  Let's say it was the third item (position 2, base 0).  What I want is a pointer to the image in the adapter view so I can toggle its visibility (image is a checkmark).  I can't seem to work my way to a specific item in the AdapterView.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution may be a hack, i'm not sure but anyway ...

So you have a TextView and a ImageView on each items of your list. Let's suppose they are on a LinearLayout. Also, you said "When the user click on the TextView", so i suppose you have a onClickListener linked to the TextView. The onClickListener gives you the reference of the TextView. You can call getParent() on that view, cast it to a ViewGroup, and findViewById() to retrieve your image. example :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) // view = TextView
{
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view.getParent(); // vg = LinearLayout
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) vg.findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);
    iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
```

I think the cast (ViewGroup) is not really safe but i can be wrong. I don't know. Try this out

If the Listener is actually a OnItemClickListener() linked to the List (because i'm not sure i understood correctly what you said) then it means that when the user click, the entire item view is sent to the listener, so you just have to do this :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    //view = LinearLayout
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);
    iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: That sounds close, let me give it a try - thanks!

Comment: Take a look at handrenliang's answer. If my answer is indeed a hack, then this is bad and you should not do it. You should try with the tags (which sounds to be a better idea). Also, select his answer instead of mine, to avoid spreading hacks in people minds :)

Comment: I don't think yours was bad; it certainly worked, but his might be more appropriate, however it's 1:30 a.m. and I'm not trying anything more tonight; I'll see if his (or hers, as the case may be) works tomorrow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the selected solution is a little bit hack. AdapterView is a View too, so you can simply set a unique tag to your ImageView in Adapter, then use AdapterView.findViewWithTag() to get the view.

Comment: Tags on views are new for me, let me experiment.

Comment: Still working on it (holiday weekend and all).  Still requires me iterating through the objects.  Regardless, plan to use them if not here then in the future.